# How to properly remove Parse and its frameworks from Xcode project?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, frameworks

how should go about properly removing parse and its frameworks out of my Xcode project? I want to completely eradicate its services out of my project, references and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the import statements then the files from your project, when you're asked choose to Move to Trash

Comment: well I'm actually just doing the cleanse so i can re - install it again.